# I am having trouble changing the range and order in my script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script that I use to track inventory and I need to add 5 more columns for inventory supplies and also change the order. More specifically, I need the t-shirt size and quantities column to come after all of the other supplies. Can someone assist with this? If you need to see the sheet, just let me know.

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Macros')
      .addItem('commit', 'invntry')
      .addToUi();
}
function invntry() {
  var ss,s1,s2,items,stock,i;
  ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  s1=ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  s2=ss.getSheetByName("Charlotte Inventory");
  items=s1.getDataRange().offset(1,8).getValues().map(function(x) {return x.slice(0,11);});//added one column
  items.pop();
  stock=s2.getDataRange().getValues().map(function(x) {return x[1];});//Inventory is now colB
  for (i in items) {
    if (items[i][10]!="yes") {

      switch (items[i][0]) {
        case 'S':
          stock[1]-=items[i][1];
          break;
        case 'M':
          stock[2]-=items[i][1];
          break;
        case 'L':
          stock[3]-=items[i][1];
          break;
        case 'XL':
          stock[4]-=items[i][1];
          break;
        case '2L':
          stock[5]-=items[i][1];
          break;
        case '3L':
          stock[6]-=items[i][1];
          break;
        case '4L':
          stock[7]-=items[i][1];
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
      for (var j=8; j<16; j++) stock[j]-=items[i][j-6];//now through row 15
      items[i][10]='yes';//10th element
    }
  }
  s2.getRange(1, 2, stock.length).setValues(stock.map(function(x) {return [x];}));//col B
  s1.getRange(2, 19, items.length).setValues(items.map(function(x) {return [x[10]];}));//col R; 11th element
}
```

Comment: What have you tried already? If you aren't sure what functions are doing, look them up on either the [MDN Javascript Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference), or for the Apps Script specific ones (like those that interact with the Spreadsheet interface), the [Apps Script Reference.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. I have tried everything I am capable of doing. I am able to add columns, but some reason I am getting undefined and another message on the sheet when I run the script. I noticed that it worked when there was a formula in a separate column. Once I removed this formula, as it was not needed, that is when I started getting messages on the sheet. When it comes to changing the order in the script, I am kind of at a loss.

Comment: It sounds like you need to spend a lot of time becoming familiar with Javascript and code in general. Viewing youtube tutorials on javascript arrays and javascript objects may be very helpful. You can look up specific functions (e.g. `getDataRange`) to see what arguments they need and what things (if any) they provide back to the caller. Walking through the code in the Script Editor by setting a breakpoint (click a line number so it shows a red circle), and then using the "bug" icon next to the run button to enter "debug" execution, will let you inspect the variables in your script at runtime